# Binary Addition Solution explanation

Tags: javascript, binary

I came across a Solution for Binary Addition and I'm having a hard time understanding how it worked. Mainly I need to know what '`>>>`' does? Here is the solution:

```
function addBinary(a,b) {
  let sum = a + b;
  return (sum >>> 0).toString(2);
}

addBinary(1,2) // 11
```

Comment: It's a binary [unsigned right shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Right_shift)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Unsigned_right_shift

Comment: `>>>` is a right shift. `>>> 0` doesn't actually shift anything, it just convert `sum` into an integer as `a` and `b` could be floating point numbers. Try it: `console.log(Math.PI >>> 0);`.